# Cannot find a certain node in a newer version of Blender

Tags: node-editor

I am following a [snow tutorial (from 2011)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REro5vzH2Oo&t=2m42s), and I am having some difficulties with the node editor in Blender v2.68. In the tutorial, an attribute, "paintmap", is added and mixed with the main view to make visible the snowflake drop effect on the ground. The problem is that, in the newer Blender version, I can't find any similar node:

[image: Screenshot of Nodes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes you want are there. Make sure that your render engine is set to *Cycles* and you are using *Shader* nodes.

[image]